# FreeBSD passenger gem (rubygem-passenger) not building for nginx

Tags: nginx, passenger, freebsd

I am trying to build rubygem-passenger for nginx on FreeBSD 11.1 but the compiler stops with Error code 1 complaining:

> 2.3/gems/passenger-5.1.8/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so failed: No such file or directory
>   *** Error code 1
>
> Stop. make[1]: stopped in /usr/ports/www/rubygem-passenger
>   *** Error code 1

Please note the section of the path where it says /apache2/mod_passenger.so

The config options are set to **nginx**!

Any help or hint is appreciated since I am stuck for days now with this problem.

Comment: There was a possibly related [bug fix](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=222438) committed a few weeks ago - you could try updating your port to 5.1.11 and see if that helps.

Comment: 5.1.11 is actually the version I've tried first. But due to several other problems that's even a far more terrible nightmare.

Comment: Have you since solved the problem, or can I try and help you out?

Answer (score 0):

You gave less information how you call the compile process.
Usually I do

```
cd /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3/gems/passenger-5.1.11
rake nginx:as_dynamic_module
```

If you call `rake -T` then you will get more options how to compile passenger.